# Calculating total distance between points

Tags: python, function, tuples

I wrote this function which finds the distance between two points. Now my next task is to write a function that takes in a list of points which are tuples and calculates the total distance by using the distance function to find the distance of each pair of points and I am stuck I don't know how to go about it any help please? This is the first function:

```py
def distance(point1, point2):
    dist = math.sqrt((point2[0] - point1[0])** 2 + (point2[1] - point1[1])** 2) 
    return dist
```

Comment: you just need to create another function, lets say `calculate_distances` with a list as an argument of that function i,e. `calculate_distances(list_distances)`. Then you will need to loop (using a for-loop) over each element of the given `list_distances`, then you will need to pass each point to the `distance` function inside that loop

Comment: Thanks i thought of that but how to write the code which properly loop through the list of points is what I can't seem to figure out. Please if you dont mind you could guide me?

Comment: Write a function called total_distance that takes in a list of points. It should use the other function you wrote to find the distance between each pair of points, and add up all the intermediate distances. It should return the total distance.

Comment: That's the task description

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an even list and each pair you want to calculate:

```
list_points = [(2,1),(50,1), (30,1), (30,5)]
for i in range(0,len(list_points),2):
    pair = list_points[i:i+2]
    dist(pair[0], pair[1])
```

The third parameter in range is a way to batch.
Then if you want to make it a function:

```
def compute_distance(list_points):
    """compute distance of points give a list of tuples"""
    computed_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(list_points),2):
        pair = list_points[i:i+2]
        computed_list.append(dist(pair[0], pair[1]))
    return computed_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import math

def calc_total_distance(point_list):
    total_dist = 0
    for i in range(len(point_list)-1):
        dist = math.sqrt((point_list[i][0] - point_list[i+1][0])** 2 + (point_list[i][1] - point_list[i+1][1])** 2)
        total_dist += dist
    return(total_dist)

point_list = [(1,2), (2,2), (2,10)]
print(calc_total_distance(point_list))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your distance function takes in two tuples as argument.
So for the new function you'd have a list containing nested tuples of the sort:

`list_points = [((2, 1), (50, 1)), ((30, 1), (30, 5))]`

Note that each tuple contains two tuples.

If this is the case, here's how I'll write the new function:

```
    def total_distance(list_distances):
        result = [distance(i[0], i[1]) for i in list_distances]
        return sum(result)
```

The second line here uses list comprehension to loop through the list and map the items to your distance function. The sum of all the distances obtained is returned

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the distanced between each pair of points. A good way to get the pairs is by using a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) like the one named `pairwise()` shown below. You're also reinventing the wheel with regards to calculating the distance between two points —  because there is a [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function.

The code below shows using them together to do what you want:

```
import math

def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."""
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def distance(point1, point2):
    return math.hypot(point2[0]-point1[0], point2[1]-point1[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = [(1,2), (2,2), (2,10)]
    print(f'total distance:', sum(distance(a, b) for a,b in pairwise(points)))
```